# 1970-01-01 is getting inserted to database when no date is selected

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a text box where date is entered in php. Since I want the date to be in particular format I am using.
`date("d.m.Y", strtotime())` to conver the date. When no date is give or if I leave the textbox blank it will enter 1970-01-01 to database. How can I solve this?
Here is my code

```
 $d_date= clean($_POST['datum']);
$newdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $d_date));
```

If `$d_date` value is null the it will enter 1970-01-01 to database.

Comment: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 is the starting time of Unix timestamps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time So if you enter `0` as timestamp, it is in fact 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: That is mostly because `strtotime()` is unable to create a time from the given string. What is contained in the `$d_date` variable?

Comment: Dupes http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+1970-01-01

Comment: $d_date value is blank.

Answer (score 9):

Make field in the database nullable, and when date is not submitted in the form set it to NULL. Default behaviour of mysql is to set date to default value, which is 1970-01-01(unix epoch)

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Do you mean to say that `strtotime( null )` or `date( 'Y-m-d', null )` returns `1970....`?

Comment: @Ravinder, `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(null))` does.

Answer (score 1):

PHP `strtotime()` returns `false` on failure. This includes if the parameter is null, blank. or any other invalidly formatted string.

So, `strtotime(null)` returns `bool(false)`.

The second parameter for the `date()` function is an integer, so when you call `date("Y-m-d", false)`, `false` gets converted to `0`, and `date("Y-m-d", 0)`, returns the epoch date.

Here's an easy way to handle this, prior to inserting the value into the database:

```
// Default to null
$newdate=null;
// Only proceed if strtotime() succeeds
if($d_date=strtotime($_POST['datum'])) {
  // Since we have a valid time, turn to date string
  $newdate=date("Y-m-d", $d_date);
}
```

Then, simply allow NULL on your date column so that null can be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

**`you can use this to check strtotime return false or true`**

```
$from_date=strtotime($_POST["from"]); 
$from_date=($from_date ? date("Y-m-d", $from_date) : '');

$to_date=strtotime($_POST["to"]);
$to_date=($to_date ? date("Y-m-d", $to_date) : '');
```