# Mysql Date Default insert in 1970-01-01

Tags: mysql, datefield

I am inserting an empty `date-field`, but a default value `1970-01-01` gets inserted automatically. Why?

I even changed the `Date` structure to allow `null`, set `Default` as `Null`, still it's inserting `1970-01-01`.

Comment: Can you show us what code you are trying to run? From your comments you are having trouble with the PHP part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely inserting an empty string. Inserting an entry string will result in 1970-01-01 being written instead. You have to really insert NULL if you don't want this to happen.

What you want to do is:

```
INSERT INTO table
SET datefield = NULL
```

Not `"NULL"` but `NULL` Otherwise it will read it as a string and not as `NULL`

You can also just don't set the column at all in your insert and than it will use `NULL` as well

Comment: Sorry for my silly question, $model->birthday = NULL ,ok am removed quotes But it still insert 1970-01-01

Comment: what you are typing in comments is PHP not MySQL? maybe edit your question to show what the code is that you are trying. this might help us a lot in helping you.

Answer (score 1):

It's the default behavior of MySQL, check in the Database that the field can be NULL.

Check this: [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308739/1970-01-01-is-getting-inserted-to-database-when-no-date-is-selected)

Comment: But can't insert date null,What's wrong in my code? $newdate = "NULL";
                $model->birthday = $newdate; am try to insert null value to date field and also changed mysql to allow Null value still its insert 1970

Comment: @priyampmp1 most likely you insert it with "" or '' around it, this will cause mysql to interpret it as a string and thus still giving you 1970, see my answer